# Converting a date to weekofyear format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to convert the following date format into the weekofyear format.

For eg.

Date : 2020-09-15 Text format
Desired Result : 202038 Text

Want to implement the same in my view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) for that:

```
to_char(the_date_column, 'iyyyiw')
```

This uses the [ISO definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) of the week.

If you need it as a number, you can cast the resulting string.

If performance matters, using [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) is a bit faster:

```
extract(isoyear from the_column) * 100 + extract(week from the_column)
```